# How to access ClientCertificate from OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httprequest, client-certificates, .net-standard-2.0

I've created an attribute (`[ValidateCertificate]`) in my Web Api to check the certificate coming into each call. I want to access the ClientCertificate property to validate the incoming certificate. This is from Microsoft's documentation:

```
public System.Web.HttpClientCertificate ClientCertificate { get; }
```

However, the property doesn't exist in my code. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    public async override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = httpContext.Request.ClientCertificate; // This property doesn't exist.
```

It looks like that property should be in an HttpRequest object, but I have access only to an HttpRequestMessage object within this attribute code. I guess it boils down to this:

1. Is the certificate contained in the incoming parameter?
2. How can I cast to a type where I can get at it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

WebApi is working with the classes specified by the documentation you checked. Aka, you saw a wrong doc.

When creating a derived attribute class from AuthorizationFilterAttribute, you will be prompted to reference a packaged called "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" from Nuget (when using dotnet core only) with a using "System.Net.Http" to your project. And 2 more using, "System.Web.Http.Controllers" and "System.Net.Http" will be required to add also. After those operations, you can use an extension method called "actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate()" to get the client certificate in OnAuthorization method.